# Encode a string to gbk in Python

Tags: python, encoding, character, gbk

I am trying to see what different strings would look like in different encodings...

For example:

```
>>> str1 = "asdf"
>>> str1.encode('utf-16')
'\xff\xfea\x00s\x00d\x00f\x00'
>>> str1.encode('base64')
'YXNkZg==\n'
```

And those all get me what I want.

But I'd like to see what certain strings would look like in gbk, gb2312, or gb18030.

```
>>> str1.encode('gbk')
'asdf'
>>> str1.encode('gb2312')
'asdf'
>>> str1.encode('gb18030')
'asdf'
```

Shouldn't the outputs be something other than 'asdf'?

I have python 2.7 and I can see the gbk.py and the other files in lib/encodings

I was wondering if I see no change in the output because those letters will show up the same in that encoding, or because I need to somehow enable the use of those encodings (some sort of import needed?)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as only byte values 0-127 are used, these encodings are equivalent to ASCII. The same is true for UTF-8. To really see the difference, try with some actual Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Wikipedia page:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK)

> A character is encoded as 1 or 2
>   bytes. A byte in the range 00–7F is a
>   single byte that means the same thing
>   as it does in ASCII. Strictly
>   speaking, there are 96 characters and
>   32 control codes in this range.

So no, your test string of ASCII characters should not encode as something different (at least not for GBK, I didn't check the varieties).